# Power goes on and off

Tags: circuit-breaker

Power to house keeps going on and off. The last time it went off I turned the main breaker off and back on and immediately had power. Could the main breaker be going bad?

Comment: Could be. Could also be a faulty connection somewhere. In any case, you don't want to mess with the unfused cables. Call a pro, or at least have the power co do a disconnect (which should be free of charge).

Comment: What type (brand of panel) do you have?

Comment: There is really not enough information to answer the question. A short term fix that may help for a while is to turn off all the breakers in the panel. then flip the main breaker on and off 10+ times. This cleans the hammer strike points and may solve the problem for a while. There are some panel types that have serious problems and this could be the start to a complete failure. What brand of panel is this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.  The definitive test is to measure the voltage *before* the main breaker when the failure occurs.

If you are handy and knowledgeable enough about electric wiring, remove the breaker box panel cover.  Probe the main lead wires coming from the meter with a voltmeter or voltage indicator during an outage.

Note that opening the panel and taking a good close visual look at the leads upstream and downstream of the main breaker might reveal the problem.  Maybe there are discolored or loose wires, melted insulation, charring, a stray wire, etc.